# Text color doesn't change in an AlertDialog when applying an app wide theme

Tags: android

(Note: build minimum and target API 7)

Ok, here is a real stumper for this newbie between the chair and the keyboard:

I am applying a them to my app, and using `AlertDialog` for some key information at a few key places (i.e. a EULA pop up on first app run). My problem is this, everything is fine until I apply a theme (or style to the Activity). My text everywhere but the pop ups formats correctly. The problem is that I am changing from the default white text on black back ground to black text on white background. The background changes on the pop ups but not the text, so the net effect is that I have a white pop up with the text there (scroll bars show for the long winded EULA) but the text is unreadable because it is the exact same color as the background.

Here is the my_style.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="main">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I know I am implementing the call correctly because everything else in the app formats correctly, what am I missing? The app works just fine when the `android:theme="@style/main"` is removed from the `<application>` tag in the manifest file (formating removed from the entire app and the dialogs are readable). Thanks for getting a newbie set straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you passed the theme to `AlertDialog`'s or `AlertDialog.Builder`'s constructor when creating the dialog?

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

Comment: +1 for an awesome answer that would work perfectly if I was developing a Honeycomb app. :-( This would have been perfect and solved the issue nicely! But, unfortunately I am building for a min API 3, target API 7. Theme support for the AlertDialog class and subclass starts in API 11. If I could give +2 I would for this answer!

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice that. Don't see any other way though.